# Let $f(z) =e^\frac1z + \frac{1}{z-1}$ and find the Laurent Series for $f(z)$ about zero in the regions $0<|z|<1$ and $|z|>1$

Tags: complex-analysis, laurent-series, singularity

Let $f(z) =e^\frac1z + \frac{1}{z-1}$ and find the Laurent Series for $f(z)$ about zero in the regions $0<|z|<1$ and $|z|>1$.

I am somewhat confident in my working for the Laurent expansion but please correct me if I am wrong:

The commonly known expansion for $e^\frac1z$ is: $$e^\frac1z=1+\frac1z+\frac1{2!z^2}+\frac1{3!z^3}+\cdots$$
which I believe is valid for all $|z|>0$ (and therefore valid for both cases in my question right?).

For $|z|>1$, we have that $\frac{1}{z-1}$ = $\frac{1}{z}$$\frac{1}{1-1/z}$ and $|\frac{1}{z}|<1$ holds for $|z|>1$ and therefore: $$\frac{1}{z-1}=\frac{1}{z}(1+\frac1z+\frac1{z^2}+\frac1{z^3}+\cdots)$$

So our answer for the Laurent expansion in the $|z|>1$ case is the sum of these two expansions, correct?

A slight tweak for the $0<|z|<1$ case, I obtained $\frac{1}{z-1}$ = $-1$$\frac{1}{1-z}$ and therefore the expansion is: $$\frac{1}{z-1}=-1(1+z+z^2+z^3+\cdots)$$
So adding this expansion to the same previous $e^\frac1z$ expansion gives us the Laurent Expansion for this $0<|z|<1$ case, right?

I would really appreciate verification of the steps of my calculations and perhaps any corrections of mistakes I may have made.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please don't ask two unrelated questions in the same post. You should post a question asking for a verification of your proof and your follow up question in another post.

Comment: You have some typos in the case $|z|>1$

Comment: Thanks, I have since removed the singularity parts of the question and posted that as a separate one. Can you please elaborate on the typos?

Comment: You wrote $\frac{1}{z-1} = \frac{1}{z} \frac{1}{z-1/z}$, which is false

Comment: Also, $|\frac{1}{z}|>1$ certainly doesn't holds for $|z|>1$

Comment: Thanks a lot, I have now corrected these errors.

Comment: And this is not a typo, but when using MathJax you should type `$a = b c$` instead of `$a$ = $b$$c$`. It's less prone error.